# How to use PHP to display active class on sub nav links?

Tags: php

I have PHP code to display the active class on links in the nav, but I'm having trouble finding a solution to applying the active class properly for the sub nav - that being the pages that are in folders outside of the root directory. Here is the code that I have!

Here is the example code: (it works on the real code)

```
<?php
    $current_page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
?>
```

This is an example for a stand alone nav link:

```
<li class="<?php if ($current_page == "index.php"){ echo "active "; }?> item"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
```

This is an example for the drop down menu:

```
<li class="<?php if ($current_page == "index.php"){ echo "active "; }?> item has-dropdown"><a href="about.php">About Us</a>...
```

---

Now the code for the sub nav's so far isn't working for me, but here it is with the real code!

```
<?php 
    $cp = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    $cf = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
?>
```

Here is an example for a stand alone nav link:

```
<li class="<?php if ($cp == "index.php"){ echo "active "; }?> item"><a href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
```

Here is an actual drop down menu from my nav.

```
<li class="<?php if ($cp == "courses.php" || $cp == "oshawa.php" && $cf == "courses" || $cp == "bowmanville.php" && $cf == "courses"){ echo "active "; }?> item has-dropdown">
    <a href="/courses.php">Courses</a> <!-- COURSES -->
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="/courses.php">Courses</a></li>
        <li><label>Locations</label></li>
        <li><a href="/courses/oshawa.php">Oshawa</a></li>
        <li><a href="/courses/bowmanville.php">Bowmanville</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

This specifically is where the code breaks, the first part works fine, but the second we add the && $cf == "courses" it breaks.

```
$cp == "oshawa.php" && $cf == "courses"
```

I don't think it's a formatting issue, I think it's just the code itself, not sure where to go from here. I'm not very good with PHP, all help is appreciated, thanks =)

Comment: check (($cp == "courses.php" || $cp == "oshawa.php") && ($cf == "courses" || $cp == "bowmanville.php") && $cf == "courses")

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to ask your question correctly. You've provided your code a description of your problem and your attempt at troubleshooting. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, (Assuming your all courses pages exist in `courses` directory itself.)

```
<?php 
    $cp = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    $cf = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
?>

<li class="<?php if ($cp == "courses.php" || $cf == "/courses"){ echo "active "; }?> item has-dropdown">
    <a href="/courses.php">Courses</a> <!-- COURSES -->
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="/courses.php">Courses</a></li>
        <li><label>Locations</label></li>
        <li><a href="/courses/oshawa.php">Oshawa</a></li>
        <li><a href="/courses/bowmanville.php">Bowmanville</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: They do indeed, I didn't think of that, I'll test that right now!

Comment: Here is my test page www.mrobertsdesign.ca/courses/oshawa.php - the code didn't work, but I am following it now which is great =)

Comment: `dirname()` returns directory name along with `/` so in your case it will return `/courses` so in If condition change it to `$cf == "/courses"`. I've updated my answer. It should work now :)

Comment: no rush! I'll be here all day tomorrow trying to figure this out any ways =p

Comment: oh wow thanks for reminding me, I didn't even see the response haha, I'll try that now!